# How to make new project and website into only one solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

How to make new project and website into only one solution?

Answer (score 1):

Create the first project, then in the Solution Explorer you can right-click the solution and "Add new project" to it.

Answer (score 1):

First create the WebSite, it will have a Solution (.sln file) but under the default settings it could be located far away from your WebSite folders.

Then add a Project to your solution like normal. If that project is a class library you will have to select it from "Add Reference, Projects tab" as well.

Conversely, you can start with a 'normal' Project and select "Add existing WebSite" from the "File" menu or the Solutions context menu.